# Can I diagonalize a 512 by 512 matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

...with Mathematica?  Or is this going to be impossible?  I don't want to start work if it is hopeless.  I've already solved the problem on a smaller scale, which involved an 8x8 matrix.  Unfortunately, because of the nature of this problem, the next length scale up jumps to 512x512.  Crazy.

Comment: Numerical or symbolical matrix? Have you tried `Eigensystem`?

Comment: matrix consists of 1's,0's,-1's, and fractions like 1/3,1/9,-1/3,-1/9.    A numerical result is fine.

Comment: If it’s finite precision numerical there’s no issue. 512 x 512 is chump change for `Eigensystem` if you want the exact result (I.e. get back fractions not decimals) that could be memory intensive.

Answer (score 6):

This should relatively easy to find out.

Make a random Matrix, find out if it's even possible to diagonalize it.

```
matA = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10, 10}];
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[matA]

*True*
```

Calculate the Eigenvectors of the matrix to use for [further calculations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix)

$$A_{\text{diag}}={T^{-1}} .A.T$$

```
matB = Transpose[Eigenvectors[matA]]
matD = Inverse[matB].matA.matB;
DiagonalMatrixQ[matD]
*True*
```

Assuming your matrix is diagonalisable to begin with, this should give you the solution you're looking for

Comment: Good point. I can do a simple test.   I'm afraid it might overload my desktop mac.  So I'll close all the other programs and I'll be ready to turn the power off if it gets stuck.

Comment: Finding the solution of the matrix is diagonalizable or not with a 512x512 matrix only took me a second or two, however i couldnt generate one randomly that was to test with. If you have one already it shouldnt take tooooo much time.

Comment: I would think that generating the random 512x512 matrix would be the easy part.

Comment: Generating a random one yes...one that is diagonalisable right away no so quick...

Comment: Because of the nature of the system I'm working with, I know the matrix is diagonalizable.  However, I guess that a random 512x512 matix won't generally be diagonalizable.

Comment: Creating the 512x512 matrix for my system is going to require a few days of thought and work.  This is why I don't have one for a quick test.

Comment: @Chris, if your matrix is e.g. Hermitian or normal, then it is guaranteed to be diagonalizable. As you have not mentioned where your matrix came from, we are only able to speculate.

Comment: After creating the 512x512 matrix for my system, I've found out that Mathematica can diagonalize it in a couple minutes.

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked, don't forget to mark as correct if this answered your question!